# PowerShell -InputFormat XML example?

Tags: xml, powershell, input

Looks like PowerShell can accept scripts in XML format, but I do not know the exact XML syntax to use, e.g

```
powershell -InputFormat XML encoded-command
```

I believe this encoding is similar to `-enc` command option

So how should one encode the PowerShell command to XML format, any ideas?

Comment: Not directly sure what you are trying to do but if you want to work with XML you could use `ConvertFrom-xml`?

Comment: @StephenMiller updated

Comment: AFAIK, format is not documented. It is input in XML format, not script. It is here to support `ScriptBlock` passing to PowerShell executable. `[PSCustomObject]@{ a=1; b=2; c=3 } | powershell { $input | % { $_.a+$_.b*$_.c } }`